# Code First com Complex Types, ao fazer Scaffolding as propriedades das Complex Types não se encontram nas views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Estou eu seguindo a apresentação do Sergey Barskiy em http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3WzYZsN0gU, onde ele demonstra a abordagem do Entity FrameWork com Code First.

Adorei, mas tive um problema.

Na apresentação, ele demonstra que posso usar Complex Types para as propriedades de minha classe POCO, e como são geradas as tabelas em banco de dados. Sucesso até aí. A apresentação dele vai até aí.

Mas depois não consegui que essas complex type fossem criadas nas views ao fazer Scaffolding com a classe. E esse é meu problema.

Criei duas classes POCO chamadas Empresa e Pessoa, ambas tem uma propriedade Endereco e uma propriedade Auditoria (que são tipos complexos).

Abaixo minhas classes POCO:

```
public class Empresa
{
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    public Auditoria Auditoria { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
}

   public class Pessoa
   {
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }

        public String Nome { get; set; }

        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

        public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

        public Auditoria Auditoria { get; set; }

        public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

        public Empresa Empresa { get; set; }
    }

public class Endereco
{
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string UF { get; set; }
}

public class Auditoria
{
    public string CriadoPor { get; set; }
    public DateTime CriadoEm { get; set; }
    public string ModificadoPor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModificadoEm { get; set; }
}
```

O problema foi na hora de fazer o Scaffolding.
Fui criar uma Controller para a Empresa, usei o template `MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework`, e escolhi como Model Class a classe `Empresa`. Porém ao gerar as views elas não tem as propriedades das classes Endereço e Auditoria :

Abaixo a view criada Create.cshtml:

```
@model CodeFirstSample.Data.Empresa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Empresa</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Para incluir o endereço e a auditoria precisei adicionar na mão , conforme exemplo abaixo, onde adicionei a Rua da propriedade Endereco e a CriadoPor da propriedade Auditoria :

```
@model CodeFirstSample.Data.Empresa

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";

}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Empresa</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class="label-control col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Endereco.Rua, new { @class="label-control col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Endereco)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Endereco.Rua)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Auditoria.CriadoPor, new { @class="label-control col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Auditoria.CriadoPor)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Auditoria.CriadoPor)
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Consegui resolver na mão, mas existe alguma forma do template T4 já incluir as propriedades de Endereço e Auditoria?

Answer (score 2):

Altere sua classe dessa forma:

```
public class Empresa
    {
        public int EmpresaId { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public int EnderecoID { get; set; }

        public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

        public int AuditoriaID {get; set}

        public virtual Auditoria Auditoria { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
    }
```

Ao realizar o scaffolding ele encontrada a propriedade EnderecoID e automaticamente irá criar uma foreign key para este campo, por padrão toda propriedade com nome de classe terminado com ID ele tentara criar uma foreign key [classeID].

A propriedade virtual é para de fato conseguir navegar nas propriedades do objeto.

Ajuste as outras classes tente o scaffolding novamente, um dropdown list será gerado na view. 
para mais informações recomendo:[Steven Sanderson's blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/28/mvcscaffolding-one-to-many-relationships/)
É sobre MVC3 porém toda a base é a mesma.

Answer (score 2):

Deste jeito que você modelou as classes, não.

No MVC, as classes dentro de `Models` são praticamente consideradas como tabelas num banco de dados relacional ou coleções em não-relacionais. Portanto, seus tipos complexos seriam como tabelas em separado, e não como extensão dos atributos do modelo `Pessoa`, como você está tentando fazer.

Se você quiser entender o funcionamento do Scaffolding, experimente executar estes comandos no **Package Manager Console**:

```
Scaffold CustomTemplate View _CreateOrEdit
Scaffold CustomTemplate View Create
Scaffold CustomTemplate View Edit
Scaffold CustomTemplate View Delete
Scaffold CustomTemplate View Index
Scaffold CustomTemplate View Details
```

Será criado um diretório na sua solution chamado `CodeTemplates`. Dentro dele há outro diretório chamado `Scaffolders`, contendo todos os templates em T4 usados para gerar as Views.